# Checking system time always and calling a function

Tags: android, arrays, systemtime

In my app I want to check system time every second and then take the time compare it with an array of number and return the value until the user closes the application. So plz can anyone help me out thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You should try this intent:

```
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
```

Make broadcast-receiver and handle every second what you want.

[Help link](http://sourabhsoni.com/how-to-use-intent-action_time_tick/)

Close application is impossiable on Android, you should either close whole and all UIs or just make application background such as service etc.

Good luck!